# PHP PDO TRY. Handling Duplicates

Tags: php, sql, pdo, try-catch

I have several data files like the following:

```
- table 1        - table 2        - table 3
 id     val        id    val        id   val
 ============      ==========       ===========
  1    one         1    uno         1    un
  2    two         4    dos         6    deux
  3    three       5    tres        7    trois
```

I'm trying to insert them in a database expecting:

```
= result table
   id   val
   ============ 
    1    one
    2    two
    3    three
    d1   uno
    4    dos
    5    tres
    dd1  un
    6    deux
    7    trois
```

The database structure is:

```
= sqlite database file: data.db
  CREATE TABLE register (
      id VARCHAR(3) PRIMARY KEY,
      val VARCHAR(16)
  );
```

I'm came up with this kind of solution:

```
<?php
$table1 = array("1"=>"one","2"=>"two","3"=>"three");
$table2 = array("1"=>"uno","4"=>"dos","5"=>"tres");
$table3 = array("1"=>"un","6"=>"deux","7"=>"trois");

$fileHandle = new PDO("sqlite:data.db");
$fileHandle->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

foreach($table1 as $key => $value){
    try{
    $fileHandle->exec("INSERT INTO `register` (id,val) VALUES ('".$key."', '".$value."');");

    }catch(PDOException $e){
    if($e->getCode()=='23000'){   // if key exists, add a "d" to differentiate
        $fileHandle->exec("INSERT INTO `register` (id,val) VALUES ('d".$key."', '".$value."');");
    }
  }
}
// keys: 1, 2, 3

foreach($table2 as $key => $value){
    try{
    $fileHandle->exec("INSERT INTO `register` (id,val) VALUES ('".$key."','".$value."');");
    }catch(PDOException $e){
    if($e->getCode()=='23000'){   // if key exists, add a "d" to differentiate
        $fileHandle->exec("INSERT INTO `register` (id,val) VALUES ('d".$key."', '".$value."');");
    }
  }
}
// keys: 1, 2, 3, d1, 4, 5

foreach($table3 as $key => $value){
    try{
    $fileHandle->exec("INSERT INTO `register` (id,val) VALUES ('".$key."', '".$value."');");
    }catch(PDOException $e){
    echo "    getCode         : ".$e->getMessage()."\n";
    if($e->getCode()=='23000'){   // if key exists, add a "d" to differentiate
        $fileHandle->exec("INSERT INTO `register` (id,val) VALUES ('d".$key."', '".$value."');");
    }
  }
}
// Signals error on the INSERT in the CATCH body

?>
```

But getting stuck on the second appearance of a key. Generating a duplicate key (d1) in the example.

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 19 UNIQUE constraint failed: register.id
```

I can see the repeating pattern, but I don't see how to condense it. Or else reTRYing the modified key.

Thanks in advance for your input.

Comment: Trying to focus my question. None of the structures can be changed; the data and the database already exist (with thousands of records). The goal is insert duplicate IDs (which constraints prevent) by adding a changing them a bit. So if we have, for the sake of argument, three records with them same id 1, 1, 1 they would insert into the database as 1, d1, dd1.

Answer (score 0):

You get an error because you setup `register.id` field as primary key which includes unique constraint and id in your tables with data are not unique. If you need `id` values from tables you get data from, a typical solution is to make a separate `id` field of integer type with autoincrement as your primary key and make another field - called for example `data_tables_id` where you store `id` value from tables you get data from.
So, your SQL for `register` table will be:

```
CREATE TABLE register (
    id Integer PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    data_table_id VARCHAR(3) PRIMARY KEY,
    val VARCHAR(16)
```

);

and insert your data like so:

```
"INSERT INTO `register` (data_table_id,val) VALUES ('$key','$value');
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that You need to change your arrays.
You can't add the same value of id when it need to be unique.
In result You want a values of id like 'dd1' and 'd1', but in arrays You have values set to '1'.